# Create a table with unknown columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this

| ID | Steps | Letters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | e |
| 1 | 3 | b |
| 2 | 1 | c |
| 2 | 2 | d |
| 3 | 1 | b |
| 3 | 2 | a |

And a query that consists of the output

|  |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| d |

My goal is to create a table/ modify the first one to get rid of the letter column, and instead, have N additional columns (where N is the number of rows in the second query above) and the output is 1 if the last step for that ID was that specific letter, 0 if that letter was in any step, and NULL if it never was. Making a table like this

| ID | a | b | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | NULL |

I assume pivoting makes sense as a way to approach it, but I don't even know where to begin

Comment: Have you looked at the `PIVOT` operator?

Comment: With a variable number of columns in the output you'll need to build a pivot query dynamically based on your second query results.

Comment: do you know apriori how many (and what) columns you should have?

Comment: @lemon The list of values in that table is the list of distinct "last values" so it's made from getting the letter at the largest step number for each ID

Comment: That was clear from the description, but it does not answer my boolean question.